# What is the difference between "else: return True" and just "return True?"

Tags: python

As I learn Python I have encountered some different styles. I am wondering what the difference between using "else" is as opposed to just putting code outside of the "if" statement. To further explain my question, here are two blocks of code below.

```
x = 5
if x == 5:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I understand that this is returning False if x != 5, but how does this code below contrast to the code above? Is it the exact same thing, or is there a slight difference? Is there a benefit of using one over the other?

```
x = 5
if x == 5:
    return True
return False
```

Comment: Good question. It is exactly the same. :-)

Comment: Readability? Preference?

Comment: I get what you mean by your question, but just pointing out that your code as written will throw a SyntaxError.

Comment: Also, `return x == 5`

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I just noticed that as I ran it the block of code needs to be put into a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It is more efficient to use if-return-return or if-else-return?](/q/9191388/90527)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, there isn't any difference, because the `if` part ends with a `return` if the condition is true, and the code will exit anyway. And if the condition is false, the `else` branch will be executed, also ending with a `return`, so the `else` is not required.

It's a matter of style, but it can be argued that the second option is preferred, IMHO is simpler to read and with less rightward drift - in fact some languages/compilers will flag it with a warning, because the `else` would be unnecessary.

The key point here is that when both branches of a conditional end with a `return` then the `else` is not mandatory. But if that's not the case, then you need to use `else`, otherwise you'll end up executing code that was not intended. For example, here you can not remove the `else`:

```
if n > 10:
  n = 1
else:
  n *= 10
```

Comment: So then is there any reason to use else at all?

Comment: In this case no, but if you weren't _returning_ from both branches, then using `else` would be mandatory.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that if you try using a string without "else" it will print the string and then "None". I'm assuming that leaving out "else" would be only boolean specific then.

Comment: It's not "boolean specific", but I'd have to see an example to understand what you did ;)

Comment: If I make an "if" statement and replace the "return True/False" with "print('hi')/bye" then it would print hi/bye and then "None" in addition

Comment: I guess that's because you're printing the value returned by the function, but my answer still applies - it you don't end with a return on both branches, then you'll get different (often erroneous) results if you omit the `else`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a *very slight* difference, but it is one you wouldn't actually care about. Given these two functions:

```
def f1():
    x = 5
    if x == 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def f2():
    x = 5
    if x == 5:
        return True
    return False
```

look at the byte code resulting from each:

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  5           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  6          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (True)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

  8     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (False)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(f2)
 11           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 12           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

 13          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (True)
             14 RETURN_VALUE

 14     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               3 (False)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

For the first function, Python still generates a pair of instructions for the unreachable implied `return None`.