# When every path in a function has a return statement is it wrong to not use an else statement?

Tags: python, pep8

I've been trying to get better at styling my code and making sure it's as readable as possible.

Would it be considered bad practice to skip the else and just have a return ?

For example with this:

```
if x == 1:
    return True
return False
```

Instead of:

```
if x == 1:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: This is often a local decision within your work group.  If you want to improve your style, I recommend that you read through the PEP-8 guidelines.

Comment: PEP-8 seems to be agnostic about this. There's one example with the first style, another with the second.

Comment: This is very opinion based, but I would just say `return x == 1` so that it's obvious and readable that we're returning whether or not `x == 1` or not

Comment: @DavyM I suspect this is a contrived example and is really part of multiple if/elif statements with a generalized fallthrough handler at the end. However, I've seen both ways in Pep8-linted code, so I would just be consistent within your team.

Comment: @Prune There is a thread about this very topic [over at Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157407/best-practice-on-if-return). Wish we had cross site dupe closing.

Comment: @ChristianDean note that question uses C syntax, it could be that due to syntax / other language features, the answer could be different for different languages.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44608516/what-is-the-difference-between-else-return-true-and-just-return-true/44608693#44608693. I point out a negligible difference in the byte code generated for each of the two in an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both styles are valid, and the python style guide ([PEP 8](https://staging.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) does not specify a preference for either.

Whichever you decide to use, be consistent with it. This will result in code that is easier to read.

from [PEP 8](https://staging.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds):

> […] code is read much more often than it is written. […] As PEP 20 says, "Readability counts".
>
> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.

Under [Programming recommendations](https://staging.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51):

> Yes:
>
> ```
> def foo(x):
>     if x >= 0:
>         return math.sqrt(x)
>     else:
>         return None
>
> def bar(x):
>     if x < 0:
>         return None
>     return math.sqrt(x)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I always returns directly when it does not impact.

I did not find reference about that, but here is my vision

Because some time you could have to do stuff like

```
for spam in bacon:
    if spam == egg:
        return spam
```

But if you want to avoid returning within the `if` statement you will have to do:

```
return_value = None

from spam in bacon:
    if spam == egg:
        return_value = spam
        break

 return return_value
```

Which result to the exact same result & execution but only add 3 non relevant lines so I finally think when this happen I always use the same rule: **return directly**.

The thing is to not go too deep with `for` / `if` / `return`, but that is not really the question here.